# session.pop() does not clear cookies

Tags: python, session, flask, session-storage

I am new to Flask framework and am playing around with it to learn it better. I am following [this](https://github.com/realpython/discover-flask) tutorial along my way.

As per the [User Authentication](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BnBjhmspw4c) tutorial in the series, I am stuck with the below:

In the tutorial, when the user logs out by hitting the `/logout` route, the first thing that happens is :

```
session.pop('logged_in', None)
```

Now as per the video mentioned above, the moment user hits the `/logout` route the cookie also gets deleted from the browser.

Now 2 questions here:

1. In my case, with the exact same setup as the tutorial, although the session might be getting invalidated from the server end, the cookie does NOT get deleted/changed in any way from the browser after the `/logout` route is hit. Is there something wrong that am doing?
2. `session.pop(...)` => how/why exactly will it delete something from the front end, the browser. It can only control things on the server, isn't it ?

For your reference below is my code (taken from the tutorial itself)

```
# import the Flask class from the flask module
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, session, flash


# create the application object
app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = 'my precious'


# use decorators to link the function to a url
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Hello, World!"  # return a string
    #return render_template(index.html)


@app.route('/welcome')
def welcome():
    return render_template('welcome.html')  # render a template


# route for handling the login page logic
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != 'admin' or request.form['password'] != 'admin':
            error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
        else:
            session['logged_in'] = True
            flash('You were just logged in')
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    flash('You were just logged out')
    return redirect(url_for('welcome'))


# start the server with the 'run()' method
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: i echo the same observation. The session stayed in the browser despite the backend flask app already popped it. So i think that flask backend cannot directly delete the session in the browser. My best guess, is maybe there is a timeout to be specified in the session?

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all session and cookie is not the same. Session is more like unique id posted to you browser and something like a key for the dictionary for you backend. So most of the time, when you change session(not session id), you just modify backend part(add or delete values in backend dictionary by that key). Not browser's cookie.
2. You understood all correct. When you pop "logged in" from session server will remember that this browser will not logged_in any more.

So cookie used here just to identify the client browser. That is it.

Comment: I understand that cookies and sessions are different. But IMHO, in our case above, it appears that the cookie is a session cookie apart from identifying the browser as well. But what puzzles me is how in the video is the cookie getting deleted by session.pop() ? You think I or the author of the video (highly unlikely) missing out something here?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the expiry time of cookie to 0, this will make it invalid

```
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('token', None)
    message = 'You were logged out' 
    resp = app.make_response(render_template('login.html', message=message))
    resp.set_cookie('token', expires=0)
    return resp
```

Comment: that makes sense and I understand that if I set the expiry time for the cookie, it would not be valid beyond it's expiry. However, what puzzles me is how in the video is the cookie getting deleted by session.pop() ? Something just doesn't seem to fit in right !

Comment: if you dig more into flask source code session dictionary is use to compose the final HTTP response object. removing logged_in from session dictionary finally sets the cookie to be removed

Answer (score 0):

To remove the cookie you want to remove, you need to set the cookie's max-age to 0, and send it back to the user's browser. You can achieve this by doing this:

```py
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    resp = make_response(render_template('login.html', message="You are logged out."))
    resp.delete_cookie('token')
    return resp
```

the `delete_cookie` method is a shorthand for calling set_cookie with the cookie's name, an empty string for the value, and `expires=0`. The method sets the max-age of the cookie to 0, which means it is immediately expired.

In some older browsers you may find that they don't handle the Expires attribute correctly, so using `delete_cookie` might be a safer choice.

It also looks more clean IMHO.